# Should I check-in my node_modules folder to my code repository?

Tags: reactjs, tfs, repository, node-modules, npm-install

I have a react app in a TFS repository.
We are a team of 3 people with a branch for each of us.

Is it recommended to have the node_modules folder in our repository or we should install the packages every time we get version?

On the other hand, I should highlight that I'm using a paid Reactjs template that uses a lot of libraries by default. I also got some errors when I installed the packages and had to add them manually.

Comment: `node_modules` usually git ignored so you need to install the packages once you clone the repository.

Comment: And make sure to check in `package.json` and `package-lock.json`

Comment: @norbitrial I'm not using git, I'm using TFS. Anyway, I'd like to know if it's a good approach due to I got some errors when I installed the packages and I had to add them manually. It's important to highlight that I'm using a paid react template that uses a lot of libraries by default.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, you should not add the `node_modules` to your version control.
If you have an artifact repository (TFS/AzDO offers this feature as *Package Management* since 2017), you should use that to store the licensed packages.

The comment properly suggested to save `package.json` and `package-lock.json` in version control to allow other developers and the CI/CD pipeline to rebuild the app.

BTW it is incorrect to say TFS as Team Foundation Server, now Azure DevOps, allows using two version control systems, Git and TFVC, since 2013.